# JavaScript - Convert Long Number to String

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

```
"" + 237498237498273908472390847239084710298374901823749081237409273492374098273904872398471298374
> '2.3749823749827392e+92'
```

I calculate IDs in a beautiful and arcane way:

```
time = new Date().getTime()
pid = process.pid
host = 0; (host +=s.charCodeAt(0) for s in os.hostname())
counter = MIPS.unique_id()

"#{host}#{pid}#{time}#{counter}"
```

Unfortunately, somewhere along the way the IDs (for example `11207648813339434616800`). Unfortunately this means they sometimes turn to `1.1207648813339434e+22`.

**UPDATE**:

It seems to be a "bug/feature"  of redis. never expected that.

```
# Bug with Big Numbers on zadd
redis = require 'redis'
r = redis.createClient()
r.zadd 'zset', '342490809809999998098', 'key', ->
    r.zscore 'zset', 'key', (_, results) ->
        console.log typeof results # string
        console.log results # 3.4249080981000002e+20
```

Comment: You won't be able to store the number. You have to somehow calculate your unique ID such that it is below 19 digits of precision (maybe using `% 1000000000000000000`).

Comment: How are you passing this to the client layer?

Comment: If you are writing it somewhere in the document then just wrap it in a Javascript string or JSON object.

Comment: @Blender how about `% 1e18`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your number gets converted to `2.3749823749827392e+92` before you concatenate the number with the string to convert it.

The only solution is to use a container format that accepts an arbitrary number of digits, which is either a string or an array.

Can you provide us with a few more details as to how you are obtaining this number?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript use 8-bytes double to store large numbers, which is 53bit precision. In your case, it is far beyond 53 bits, so you should use a big-number library, which can store big numbers precisely. Try [javascript-bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum)